# How can I visualize progress in a panel?

Tags: python, interface

I want to put a list with progression bars into a panel or somewhere else. Is it possible to place a custom image next to text? Or draw progress bars like the one in the header somewhere else?

I found this line in space_info.py:    layout.template_running_jobs()
but I'm not clear about how to find the corresponding code.

My workarounds would be to use a crude text version of a progress bar or a slider. But my ideal thing would be a bar with colors of my own choosing.

Comment: Of some relevance might be: [Blender UI Multithreading Progressbar](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1050/blender-ui-multithreading-progressbar)

Comment: Take a look at this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/144212/35301

Answer (score 1):

**No** you can't (not without fairly bad hacks at least).

As of 2.69 this is a limitation in the Python API, `layout.template_running_jobs()` shows progress for blenders job system which Python has no access to.

You can however control the mouse cursor to [display progress](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_68_release/bpy.types.WindowManager.html?highlight=progress#bpy.types.WindowManager.progress_begin).

Comment: 'No, you can't at all' or just 'no, the thin progress bar is sacred as of now'? My goal is to visualize progress of something, not to explicitly use template_running_jobs(). I'd like a nice version in a panel, but if it's completely impossible, I'm prepared to use text files, even images in the image editor to work around. Progress report in a 3D panel comes to mind. or using grease pencil (: Scarcity makes inventive. So the main question remains: how can I visualize progress in a panel?

Comment: The main answer remains - you **can't**, Well, I wouldn't know of any *good* ways to do this. You can of course draw ASCII art into a panel which represents a progress bar, or abuse a slider (and make it readonly), then use a timer+modalOperator to force regular redraws. But such code is really hackish and I wouldn't accept into Blender or consider it a supported function.

Comment: I do not plan anything that requires to be accepted by you or others. But I am surprised by the limited means of blender's UI when it comes to visual communication.

Comment: @Haunt_House, yep, Blender is limited in this respect. However I dont think its always such a bad thing, we only draw progress in the header info currently, so Python tools should follow this also. Then users get predictable experience and know what to expect.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't ever done this so it's just a thought, but could you use [layout.split](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_68_release/bpy.types.UILayout.html?highlight=split#bpy.types.UILayout.split) with increasing percentages as a slightly less crude progress bar? Perhaps with a blank operator button on the left and an empty label (or button with emboss=False) on the right. This should automatically stretch to fill the available space in the panel.

Search for 'split' in the [Cookbook Code Snippets](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.5/Py/Scripts/Cookbook/Code_snippets/Interface) for some example usage.