# Custom Render Engine with bgl

Tags: rendering, opengl

I need to code my own Render Engine to do specific rendering passes. I don't want to build my own Blender app by coding in c/c++, so i try to make it work in Python.

But i need OpenGL functions.

Inside the render function, I call bgl functions to use OpenGL. This allows me to compute the render of the scene in a fast way and get the result from OpenGL to display it on the Blender editor.

CustomRenderEngine.py :

```
import bpy
import math
from mathutils import * 
from bgl import * 
import time

class CustomRenderEngine(bpy.types.RenderEngine):

    bl_idname = "custom_renderer"
    bl_label = "Custom Renderer"
    use_preview = True

    def render(self, scene):

        scale = scene.render.resolution_percentage / 100.0
        width = int(scene.render.resolution_x * scale)
        height = int(scene.render.resolution_y * scale)

        # Get mesh objects and cameras 
        camera_objects = []
        mesh_objects = []
        for obj in scene.objects:
            print("\tName:%s \tType:%s"%(obj.name,obj.type))
            if obj.type == 'MESH':
                mesh_objects.append(obj)
            elif obj.type == 'CAMERA':
                camera_objects.append(obj)


        if len(camera_objects) == 0:
            print("No camera found.")
            return


        # Ideally, we could render for each camera in the scene
        camera = camera_objects[0]
        z_near = camera.data.clip_start
        z_far = camera.data.clip_end
        lens = camera.data.lens
        factor = lens / 32.0
        pr = float(width) / float(height)
        fovx = math.atan(.5/factor) 
        fovy = math.atan(.5/pr/factor)
        fov = fovy * 360 /math.pi   

        modelview_matrix = camera.matrix_world.inverted()

        # OpenGL init
        glClearColor( 1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0)
        glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
        glLoadIdentity()
        glViewport(0,0,width,height)
        gluPerspective(fov, pr, z_near, z_far)
        glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW )
        glLoadIdentity()
        glShadeModel( GL_SMOOTH)

        for obj in mesh_objects:
            print("Handle Object : %s"%obj.name)
            mesh = obj.data
            diffuse_color = mesh.materials[0].diffuse_color
            print("Diffuse color: %s"%diffuse_color)

            for polygon in mesh.polygons:
                glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
                for vertex_id in polygon.vertices:

                    # This is quite simple for now, only diffuse color and geometry
                    vertex = mesh.vertices[vertex_id]
                    v = modelview_matrix * obj.matrix_local * vertex.co
                    glColor3f(diffuse_color[0],diffuse_color[1],diffuse_color[2])
                    glVertex3f(v[0],v[1],v[2])
                glEnd()

        # Get the result from Open GL
        colBuff = Buffer(GL_FLOAT, (height,width,3))
        glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT,colBuff ) 

        # Write the result to Blender preview
        output_pixels = []
        for y in range (0,height):
            for x in range(0,width):
                col = colBuff[y][x]
                output_pixels.append([col[0],col[1],col[2],1.0])


        result = self.begin_result(0, 0, width, height)
        layer = result.layers[0].passes["Combined"]
        layer.rect = output_pixels
        self.end_result(result)


def register() :
    bpy.utils.register_class(CustomRenderEngine)

    from bl_ui import (properties_render)
    properties_render.RENDER_PT_render.COMPAT_ENGINES.add(CustomRenderEngine.bl_idname)

def unregister() :
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(CustomRenderEngine)

    from bl_ui import (properties_render)
    properties_render.RENDER_PT_render.COMPAT_ENGINES.remove(CustomRenderEngine.bl_idname)
```

__ init __.py

```
bl_info = {
    'name': 'CustomEngineTest',
    'category': 'SVG Render',
    'version': (0, 0, 1),
    'blender': (2, 78, 0)
}

modulesNames = ['CustomRenderEngine']

import sys
import importlib

modulesFullNames = {}
for currentModuleName in modulesNames:
    if 'DEBUG_MODE' in sys.argv:
        modulesFullNames[currentModuleName] = ('{}'.format(currentModuleName))
    else:
        modulesFullNames[currentModuleName] = ('{}.{}'.format(__name__, currentModuleName))

for currentModuleFullName in modulesFullNames.values():
    if currentModuleFullName in sys.modules:
        importlib.reload(sys.modules[currentModuleFullName])
    else:
        globals()[currentModuleFullName] = importlib.import_module(currentModuleFullName)
        setattr(globals()[currentModuleFullName], 'modulesNames', modulesFullNames)

def register():
    for currentModuleName in modulesFullNames.values():
        if currentModuleName in sys.modules:
            if hasattr(sys.modules[currentModuleName], 'register'):
                sys.modules[currentModuleName].register()

def unregister():
    for currentModuleName in modulesFullNames.values():
        if currentModuleName in sys.modules:
            if hasattr(sys.modules[currentModuleName], 'unregister'):
                sys.modules[currentModuleName].unregister()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

When I started Blender from command line and call render with a script (start_addon.py), bgl function calls work as expected.

For example :

Scene :
[image: Scene]

Result :
[image: Result]

start_addon.py

```
import os
import sys
import bpy
from bgl import * 


filesDir = os.getcwd()

initFile = "__init__.py"

if filesDir not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(filesDir)

file = os.path.join(filesDir, initFile)

if 'DEBUG_MODE' not in sys.argv:
    sys.argv.append('DEBUG_MODE')

exec(compile(open(file).read(), initFile, 'exec'))

if 'DEBUG_MODE' in sys.argv:
    sys.argv.remove('DEBUG_MODE')

bpy.context.scene.render.engine = "custom_renderer"
bpy.ops.render.render()
```

But when I manually set the render engine inside Blender UI and press "Render" Button, i got a segmentation fault with this backtrace :

```
# Blender 2.79 (sub 0), Commit date: 2017-09-11 10:43, Hash 5bd8ac9

# backtrace

0   blender   

                          0x0000000100c32b1a BLI_system_backtrace + 58

1   blender                             0x000000010013ee1a sig_handle_crash + 362

2   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x00007fffc571fb3a _sigtramp + 26

3   blender                             0x0000000102293ea6 PyObject_CallMethodObjArgs + 406

4   blender                             0x000000010059861c Method_ClearColor + 76

5   blender                             0x00000001022d93f8 PyCFunction_Call + 280

6   blender                             0x00000001023540f2 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 26210

7   blender                             0x000000010235853f fast_function + 223

8   blender                             0x0000000102353bbb PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 24875

9   blender                             0x0000000102357cc5 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 2421

10  blender                             0x000000010234da6e PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 78

11  blender                             0x00000001022bb7ad function_call + 381

12  blender                             0x00000001022935c0 PyObject_Call + 96

13  blender                             0x000000010057650d bpy_class_call + 1069

14  blender                             0x0000000100b3e851 engine_render + 113

15  blender                             0x00000001004f982b RE_engine_render + 971

16  blender                             0x000000010050f190 do_render_3d + 48

17  blender                             0x000000010050d8a1 do_render_fields_blur_3d + 289

18  blender                             0x000000010050c984 do_render_all_options + 388

19  blender                             0x000000010050c42e RE_BlenderFrame + 206

20  blender                             0x000000010044786b render_startjob + 139

21  blender                             0x0000000100150c2f do_job_thread + 31

22  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fffc572993b _pthread_body + 180

23  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fffc5729887 _pthread_body + 0

24  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fffc572908d thread_start + 13
```

It crashes on macOS high Sierra and also Sierra.
Any ideas ?

Edit : 
Weirdest thing, if I tape in Python console 
bpy.ops.render.render() it works.
But the Render button, which should call bpy.ops.render.render() finishes with the seg fault.

Thx in advance,

Comment: [Rleated](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52711/how-to-render-with-a-custom-render-engine) Can you please expand and correct some errors , eg `bl_idname` is lower case "customRender",  and how have you defined `mesh_objects`.  Suggest putting in the `import bpy` (and bgl)  and register methods for class too.  Makes it easier for those interested to test, and hence answer.  (even though it breaks question rules somewhat)

Comment: Just Updated the post.