# Printing items too many times?

Tags: python, game-engine

I am starting to have a lot of scripts going on at the same time, **most of which go on every tick and print on every tick.** When I go to the console to see what is going on, I see a ton of items repeating the same thing line after line. Is there a way to keep this under control? Perhaps it will only print if something changed? If I do that then stuff that is always supposed to be changing will keep printing. How can I keep this under control? Thanks.

Comment: This is really a Python question and not Blender specific. But have you tried the 'logging' module to log program states, and only print to the console properties you care about?

Comment: You can also use the sys module for output and '\r' to rewrite the same line. This way you could output only a list of variables on every line that changes value. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3219/how-to-show-to-the-user-a-progression-in-a-script/30739#30739