# Blender 2.79 Numeric Loading Cursor (like the timer or beachball, only with numbers)

Tags: interface

[image: Blender Loading Cursor with Digits]

Blender has a special cursor when you run an operation that taxes the system. I always thought it was a progress counter, but the numbers do not add up.

Can anybody tell me, what those numbers in the rectangle are displaying?

[image: Blender 2.79 Loading Cursor while Loading an OBJ File]

In this example, I simply loaded in an OBJ. I would expect the numbers to go up to 100, but for some reason, they do not.

Comment: The last huge file I loaded in made the upper and lower line go up to 66 and then it was done. Based on that, it does not look like a loading bar to me.

Comment: Those two lines move independently,  by which I mean the top and bottom number seem not connected. It is a conundrum.

Comment: I don't think I'll be able to help you with this, but to increase your chances of getting an answer, I would suggest adding to your question: (1) the version of blender and your operating system, (2) an example of operation that triggers the "progress" status of the pointer, so that people can see what you're seeing

Comment: Good call, I'll try to get some footage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### In short

You are reading: «**33.33 percent, 66.66 percent, done**», or more literally «**3333 per ten thousand** (‱), **etc**». These percentages don't necessarily correspond to a "fraction of the evaluation time", but more likely to a "fraction of the total number of steps", in this case: 3.

### In detail

The cursor displays the current progress, mapped to the range 0 to 9999.
It is called, for instance, in [`$SOURCE/blender/makesrna/intern/rna_wm_api.c`](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/makesrna/intern/rna_wm_api.c) like this:

```
static void rna_progress_update(struct wmWindowManager *wm, float value)
{
  if (wm_progress_state.is_valid) {
    /* Map to cursor_time range [0,9999] */
    wmWindow *win = wm->winactive;
    if (win) {
              int val = (int)(10000 * (value - wm_progress_state.min) / (wm_progress_state.max - wm_progress_state.min));
              WM_cursor_time(win, val);
    }
  }
}
```

where a given "`value`" is compared to a "`min`" and a "`max`" and expressed as "`val`" in terms of a fraction of 10,000 of the (min, max) interval. The function `WM_cursor_time` from [`$SOURCE/blender/windowmanager/intern/wm_cursors.c`](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/windowmanager/intern/wm_cursors.c) takes care of "visualising" the cursor.

Of course script creators can pass to the cursor number mapped to 1-100, or 1-1000 if they want: "WM_cursor_time" doesn't check that the number is a fraction of 10000. So it really depends on context here!

In your case, probably the process of loading an OBJ has three checkpoints, that were hard-assigned to 1/3, 2/3 and 3/3 and don't necessarily correspond linearly to their evaluation time. These fractions, mapped to 10000, with the decimal part ignored ("floor" rounding) are `3333`, `6666` and `10000`.

I speculate that what you are seeing are just the first two of these numbers while "`10000`" (`999`) is skipped because it's probably overridden by the next event.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was going bonkers not knowing! For further reference, can you point me to some kind of documentation where I can read up on the name of the inner gears of Blender?

I feel that might come in handy in the future!

Comment: I might not be the best person to point you in that direction: I don't know if there are manuals for the source code of blender, and I myself have just a limited knowledge of what's inside. There is an intermediate level though, used for scripting applications and add-ons that work with blender, that is the Blender Python API. That one is well documented on the blender website.

Answer (score 2):

**Show progress with cursor.**

As outlined in [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/3297/15543) the progress of a script can be displayed using the cursor.

Set the start number with [`WindowManager.progress_begin(min, max)`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.WindowManager.html?highlight=progress_begin#bpy.types.WindowManager.progress_begin) update with `wm.progress_update(i)` and finish with `wm.progress_end()`

*Code from link*

```
import bpy
wm = bpy.context.window_manager

# progress from [0 - 1000]
tot = 1000
wm.progress_begin(0, tot)
for i in range(tot):
    wm.progress_update(i)
wm.progress_end()
```

As pointed out via [code in @NicolaSap's Answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/123731/15543) the 4 digit number displayed will range from 0 to 9999 .. or think of a as a 0 to 99.99% (the 1438 in q image would be 14.38% based on how many lines in file or s....(consult addon code).. ) progress or as a fraction of 1 [0, 0.9999] where 1 is complete.

The code above will start at 0, step up by 10, 1000 times.