# How to create a subpanel that has a checkbox - Python Blender

Tags: python, scripting, panel

I am creating an Addon with Python and BPY, and I would want to have something like this:

[image: This seems to be like a subpanel]

How are these things called? Subpanels? I have been looking and couldn't find any info.

I would like to know how to create them, I have a panel that needs to be better organized and I want it to have multiple "subpanels" with checkboxes so I can disable them like this one:

[image: I would like to put a checkbox too!]

Comment: Sub panel example: [How do a create a foldout UI panel?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/155517/31447), introduced in 2.8x, official wiki: https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.80/Python_API/UI_API

Comment: @brockmann I have looked at that answer but it didn't seem to work for me, maybe they have changed the API in 2.90. But thanks! The subpanel comment is what I was looking for, thanks! Create and answer and I will set it as solved!

Comment: What exactly does not work? No changes: https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.90/Python_API

Comment: It executes but it does not create a checkbox, but I think I can workaround that by creating the property apart in a property group I have

Comment: Blender 2.90, no isses -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewRrN.png Note: One object needs to be in context...

Comment: I'm guessing it has to be in the object tab too? Mine is in the render tab, that may be the issue