# how do I add these sub panels to a panel in my addon?

Tags: interface, add-on, panel

[image]

I know how to make a basic bpy.types.Panel, but how do I add these sub panels?

Comment: A sub panel like shown above is a complete panel object which includes a `bl_parent_id` reference to the upper panel.

Comment: that works! thank you so much :3

Comment: @Ratt can write that as an answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do a create a foldout UI panel?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/155515/how-do-a-create-a-foldout-ui-panel)