# showing progress to the user within blocking code

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, operator

The goal is to give feedback to the user when running long blocking tasks in an addon. There is already a question with great answers from 9 years ago that should be mentioned:
[How to show to the user a progression in a script?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3219/how-to-show-to-the-user-a-progression-in-a-script)

The solution suggested from ideasman42 using wm.progress_begin ist still working in Blender 3.4.1 But it would be great to give the user more specific information. Like suggested from Robin Betts i am asking this as a new question. Maybe there are some new approaches.

The info operator looks like a very clean method to me. Anyway: I am struggling to get the state updated during the script. Is it even possible to interact with the gui from within blocking code? Of course i would like to avoid unjoined threads and approaches like „bpy.ops.wm.redraw_timer(type='DRAW_WIN_SWAP', iterations=1)“

This is a minimal example of the problem and my current approach.

```
import bpy

from bpy.types import (Panel, Operator)
from time import sleep

# operater to start the blocking job
class WM_OT_job(Operator):
    bl_label = "job"
    bl_idname = "wm.job"

    def execute(self, context):
        self.report({'INFO'}, "starting job ...") # this info is lost
        for i in range(10):
            text = "the current state is " + str(i)
            self.report({'INFO'}, text) # this infos are lost too
            sleep(0.25)
        self.report({'INFO'}, "done") # this info is printed
    
        return {"FINISHED"}


# simple panel
class test(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
    bl_label = "test"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_custom_panel"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "test"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        box = layout.box()
        
        box.operator("wm.job", text="todo")


# register and unregister
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(test)
        
    from bpy.utils import register_class
    register_class(WM_OT_job)


def unregister():
    unregister_class(WM_OT_job)
        
    from bpy.utils import unregister_class
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(test)


# mainloop
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```