# How do I Download an External File from URL and Display Progress in a Panel without blocking the UI?

Tags: python, interface, path

I've read the following answers already on SE, but I cannot yet seem to replicate the end result I need in Blender 2.71.

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13485720/blender-python-scripting-trying-to-prevent-ui-lock-up-while-doing-large-calcula/16744008#16744008
- [Blender not responding while running my script](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7468/blender-not-responding-while-running-my-script/7470#7470)
- [Blender UI Multithreading Progressbar](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1050/blender-ui-multithreading-progressbar)

I'm running a panel script that uses an operator button to download a file from an external URL. I've not yet found a way to do this without blocking the UI.

I've tested modal operators and used multithreading, no luck yet. Can anyone demonstrate that this is actually possible?

If it is possible, I would then use a modal operator timer to check on the progress and update a label in the ui panel.

Here's my attempt via a modal operator timer similar to the first link in the list.

```
import bpy
import sys
import urllib
from urllib import request
from urllib.request import urlretrieve


def reporthook(blocknum, blocksize, totalsize):
    readsofar = blocknum * blocksize
    if totalsize > 0:
        percent = readsofar * 1e2 / totalsize
        s = "\r%5.1f%% %*d / %d" % (percent, len(str(totalsize)), readsofar, totalsize)
        sys.stderr.write(s)
        if readsofar >= totalsize: # near the end
            sys.stderr.write("\n")
    else: # total size is unknown
        sys.stderr.write("read %d\n" % (readsofar,))



class ModalTimerOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Operator which runs its self from a timer"""
    bl_idname = "wm.modal_timer_operator"
    bl_label = "Modal Timer Operator"

    _timer = None
    _updating = False
    _download_done = False

    def do_download(self):
        print("starting file download")

        #actual url and local path removed for privacy
        urlretrieve("REMOTE_URL", "LOCAL_DEST", reporthook) 

        self._download_done = True


    def modal(self, context, event):

        if event.type == 'TIMER' and not self._updating:
            self._updating = True
            self.do_download()
            self._updating = False

        if self._download_done:
            self.cancel(context)

        return {'PASS_THROUGH'}

    def execute(self, context):
        wm = context.window_manager
        self._timer = wm.event_timer_add(2, context.window)
        wm.modal_handler_add(self)
        self._updating = False
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def cancel(self, context):
        wm = context.window_manager
        wm.event_timer_remove(self._timer)


def register():

    bpy.utils.register_class(ModalTimerOperator)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ModalTimerOperator)    
    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()        



bpy.ops.wm.modal_timer_operator()
```

Comment: Next, I'd try activating an instance of headless Blender that will silently work in the background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Screenshot of Download Test Panel]

Okay, I think I've found the solution to this issue.

Instead of calling a single download file command with `urlretrieve`, I opened a remote `urllib.request` using the chunk size argument, as well as opening a local file for writing. I used a modal operator to read a new chunk from the URL and write the chunk to the file. **Keeping the chunk size around 16kB seemed to work well.**

In order to get the download size progress updated to a panel label, I needed to use a second modal operator running to get the label to update.

Curiously, in the Event.Timer statement of the second MO, I needed to update any random property in the scene context to get the Status Label to really update properly. Perhaps someone could explain that bit further.

This is what I used to trigger the update in the second MO:

```
bpy.context.window_manager.name = bpy.context.window_manager.name
```

Here's my code sample, feel free to comment:

```
import bpy
import sys
import urllib
from urllib import request

scn = bpy.context.scene
fileDwnProgress = ""
url = "REMOTEFILEURL"
theFile = "LOCALFILEPATH"

def strMsgLabel_Get(self):
    global fileDwnProgress
    return fileDwnProgress

bpy.types.Scene.strMsgLabel = bpy.props.StringProperty(
    name="Status", 
    description="Message Label", 
    get=strMsgLabel_Get, 
    set=None)


class OBJECT_PT_TESTPANEL(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "DOWNLOAD TEST PANEL"
    bl_space_type = "NODE_EDITOR"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_context = "object"

    def draw_header(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.label(text="", icon="INFO")

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text=scn.strMsgLabel)


class mdFileDownload(bpy.types.Operator):

    bl_idname = "wm.md_file_download"
    bl_label = "File Download"

    _timer = None
    _transferring = False
    _download = False
    _chunkSize = 16 * 1024  #(16kB seems good chunk size)
    _fileSize = 0
    _fp = None
    _req = None
    _chunk = None

    def modal(self, context, event):

        global fileDwnProgress
        global url 
        global theFile

        if event.type == 'TIMER' and not self._transferring and not self._download:

            self._fp = open(theFile, 'wb')
            self._req = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
            self._transferring = True

        if event.type == 'TIMER' and self._transferring:

            self._chunk = self._req.read(self._chunkSize)

            if sys.getsizeof(self._chunk) < self._chunkSize: 
                self._fp.write(self._chunk)
                self._fileSize += self._chunkSize
                self._transferring = False
                self._download = True  
                self._fp.close()
            else: 
                self._fp.write(self._chunk)
                self._fileSize += self._chunkSize

            progress = str(round((self._fileSize/1024/1024),1)) + " MB"
            fileDwnProgress = progress


        if self._download:
            fileDwnProgress = "Download complete!"
            self.cancel(context)

        return {'PASS_THROUGH'}


    def execute(self, context):
        # print(var)
        wm = context.window_manager
        self._timer = wm.event_timer_add(0.01, context.window)
        wm.modal_handler_add(self)
        self._transferring = False
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def cancel(self, context):
        wm = context.window_manager
        wm.event_timer_remove(self._timer)



class mdDownloadMonitor(bpy.types.Operator):

    bl_idname = "wm.md_download_monitor"
    bl_label = "Download progress monitor"

    _timer = None

    def modal(self, context, event):

        if event.type == 'TIMER':
            #this is required to trigger the update
            bpy.context.window_manager.name = bpy.context.window_manager.name

        return {'PASS_THROUGH'}

    def execute(self, context):
        wm = context.window_manager
        self._timer = wm.event_timer_add(0.01, context.window)
        wm.modal_handler_add(self)
        bpy.ops.wm.md_file_download()
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def cancel(self, context):
        wm = context.window_manager
        wm.event_timer_remove(self._timer)



def register():

    bpy.utils.register_class(OBJECT_PT_TESTPANEL)
    bpy.utils.register_class(mdFileDownload)
    bpy.utils.register_class(mdDownloadMonitor)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(OBJECT_PT_TESTPANEL)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(mdFileDownload) 
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(mdDownloadMonitor)
    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()        

bpy.ops.wm.md_download_monitor()
```

Comment: Perhaps Campbell (@ideasman42) or Brecht (@brecht) could chime in and explain why this solution works, and better yet, if there is a better way to accomplish this.