# Download external zip (with images) file and unpack it

Tags: append

Have an addon and it works well now https://github.com/Gl2imm/Apex-Toolbox

Have the intention to add in some of the items for easy use, but the images there are huge and not everyone wants to download addon with 200-300Mb size. Good option is to Optionally download External zip file with images and unpack it, so additional options will pop up to append them.

There is not much info/example about downloads here. Cant figure out at least simple logic for it to work. I looked in Easy PBR code and here [How do I Download an External File from URL and Display Progress in a Panel without blocking the UI?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21494/how-do-i-download-an-external-file-from-url-and-display-progress-in-a-panel-with) but is way too complicated setup.

What I'm trying to do is a simple button on the panel that says "Download additional files" maybe with a progress bar (if its too complicated maybe with just a status like Download Started/Download Complete).

If someone have good working examples pls share.

Comment: What exactly is the problem with this [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/21497/53513)? There's only so much reduction in complexity that can be achieved. This isn't part of the blender api, so you'll inherently have to dive into something a bit more complex. It doesn't seem that hard.

Comment: That sample i tried it didnt work. If at least it were workable solution then i could step by step alter it for my needs. Im not very good at python, so were looking for a simple solutions. This project is useful for 3D Artist community, so im doing as much as i can within my knowledge ))